# Hide columns while editing data in pgAdmin

Tags: pgadmin

I'm trying to edit data in PostgreSQL using pgAdmin and was wondering if there is any way to hide certain columns which I'm not dealing with?

Comment: What program are you using to edit the data?

Comment: @ Bob Jarvis - pgAdmin 3. I've just clicked 'View Data' then was going to edit data in there.